# How do I calculate the calories and proteins intake given these parameters?

Tags: strength-training, calories, dumbbells, daily-caloric-intake

I know it depends on many parameters, and it's subjective.
I'm asking for an approximation, I don't need exact values.

My goal is to get "bigger", to gain muscles weight.

I'm 1.85m. 75.3 Kgs.

Due to corona virus quarantene, I'm always at home, and I do strength exercise 3 times per week.
If you need info about how "strong" I am, at the moment for a set of 3 repetitions I can lift 2x20kg dumbbells with a floor press or reverse lunges. But I can provide more info if needed.

I'm using these apps to compute calories intake, but it looks to me they are suggesting around 2700calories per day.. but isn't it too much?

thanks

Comment: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/41827/how-many-calories-does-the-human-body-naturally-burn-per-day/41828#41828

Comment: You need around 1 gram of protein per kg of bodyweight.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to gain weight, I suggest you focus just on eating more. Lifting heavier weights, or the same weights for more reps, would help too. Calculating exactly how much more to eat might be nice, but the main thing is to eat a lot.

But no, 2700 calories sounds relatively little for someone your size who works out and wants to get bigger. Eat, especially protein, and lift hard.

Comment: Thanks. And if I don't eat more, what\'s going to happen? I'm going to lose the belly? :) Or am I going to waste my exercise?

Comment: Exercise is almost never totally wasted. But you said your goal was to get bigger and add muscle weight – that's hard if you don't eat, especially protein.

Answer (score 1):

For your current level of conditioning, there is scant need to concern yourself with the amount of protein that you are consuming, unless your diet is particularly restrictive. Most people in the industrialised world consume *far* more protein than they require, and the figures thrown around in body-building circles are greatly exaggerated and contrary to the science. If you eat excessively, you *will* put on mass, but it will be fat mass. Fat is not contractile and in no way contributes to your strength, or to the size you are no doubt seeking.

Guidelines from the national institutes of sport around the world are surprisingly consistent, with guidelines for protein consumption for "bodybuilding" generally given as around 1.5-1.7 grams per *kilogram* of body mass (or 0.7-0.8 grams per pound). Slight excess beyond that point will do you no harm, but it is only going to contribute to your total energy consumption.

As for your energy consumption, many tables and formulae can be found. The Katch-McArdle formula is one particularly good one, since it accounts for the fact that energy requirement is based primarily on physical size and *lean* mass. (There are numerous web sites that provide calculators for this.) Although it has been demonstrated that we can still gain muscle mass on a restrictive diet, such gain is certainly less than ideal. Therefore, it is important that you try to achieve the minimum *multiplied by* some factor—typically around 1.4-1.5 times your predicted Basal Metabolic Rate for an active (training) individual—so as not to limit your gain.

As a final note, keep in mind that you require carbohydrates to get maximum gain, since glucogen (muscle and liver stores of sugar) is required for you to lift at your potential, and insulin is anabolic.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Get an app that counts calories like MyFitnessPal or something, and log everything you normally eat for about a week or two. This will provide you with an idea of how much calories you need to maintain your current weight at the given level of exercise. Then once you have a baseline, you can increase calories per day so that you are in energy excess and you will begin to put on muscle, provided you workout out and eat relatively clean. I'd say 1.2-1.5 g of protein per lb of bodyweight is enough, and then maybe 50% of total calories from carbs roughly. Then the rest can come from fats.